# I can't edit my UL table

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm working in dreamweaver andI want to be able to edit the menu in my code, I've tried changing the position etc. but nothing happens. The only thing that makes a change to the appearance is if I change the cellpadding.

I'm quite new to this and I'd appriciate if I could get help!

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a link of my html/css http://jsfiddle.net/CGS4L/

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You wanted to change your navigation items?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with your menu? are you trying to change the css ? or ?

Comment: I'm trying to change the css and the navigation of it. :)